# ¿Árbol de jerarquía de elementos en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Quisiera saber si existe algún complemento o opción en Visual Studio (2012) en Windows Forms para ver los elementos con los que estamos trabajando en pantalla. A veces se me hace muy difícil seleccionar elementos porque quedan detrás de otros. Lo que busco es un árbol como este en el cual pueda seleccionar desde ahí los elementos. Otra ayuda sería poder ocultarlos de la pantalla.

[image]

Comment: pero si tienes visible el "Explorador de Soluciones"? o no crees que eso sea suficiente?

Comment: No es suficiente, ni ayuda ya que lo que necesito es seleccionarlo en el diseñador. Al hacer click en un elemento en el explorador de solución solo me manda a su definición en el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Visual Studio 2015 existe el Esquema del documento. Lo encuentras en "Ver->Otras ventanas->Esquema del documento". Dice que las teclas de acceso directo son Ctrl + W, U

Ojalá sea igual en VS2012

Saludos!

Comment: Uf al fin, era eso, muchísimas gracias!!!